# Passing bean route template parameters to a bean endpoint in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Camel 4.0.0-RC2 and following the [documentation on binding beans to a RouteTemplate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-template.html#_binding_beans_to_route_template). I have a simple route template to consume from a configurable `fromEndpointUri` and pass a configurable `foo` to my `fooConsumer`:

```java
routeTemplate("myTemplate")
  // Define the parameters for the route template.
  .templateParameter ("fromEndpointUri")
  .templateBean      ("foo", Foo.class)

  // Define the route.
  .from ("{{fromEndpointUri}}")
  .bean (fooConsumer, "processFoo(${body}, #{{foo}})");
```

The route I create using the template is simply:

```java
templatedRoute("myTemplate")
  .routeId   ("myTemplateRoute")
  .parameter ("fromEndpointUri", "direct:test")
  .bean      ("foo", Foo.class, ignored -> new Foo());
```

When sending a message through this route, an error is thrown `No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.example.Foo`. The relevant stack trace is:

```
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.example.Foo
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:279) ~[camel-base-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$ParameterExpression.evaluateParameterValue(MethodInfo.java:717) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    ... 94 more
Wrapped by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.ParameterBindingException: Error during parameter binding on method: public java.util.List com.example.FooConsumer.processFoo(java.lang.String,com.example.Foo) at parameter #1 with type: class com.example.Foo with value type: class java.lang.String and value: #foo-1
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$ParameterExpression.evaluateParameterValue(MethodInfo.java:728) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$ParameterExpression.evaluateParameterExpressions(MethodInfo.java:618) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$ParameterExpression.evaluate(MethodInfo.java:591) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.initializeArguments(MethodInfo.java:262) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.createMethodInvocation(MethodInfo.java:270) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.createInvocation(BeanInfo.java:266) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:128) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:81) ~[camel-bean-4.0.0-RC2.jar:4.0.0-RC2]
    ...
```

How do I pass the route's instance of `Foo` to my `FooConsumer`? Some variations I have tried are:

| Variation | Error |
| --- | --- |
| `.bean(fooConsumer, "processFoo(${body}, {{foo}})")` | `No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.example.Foo` |
| `.to("bean:fooConsumer?method=processFoo(${body},#{{foo}})")` | `No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.example.Foo` |
|  |  |
| `.to("bean:fooConsumer?method=processFoo(${body},{{foo}})")` | `No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.example.Foo` |
| `.bean(fooConsumer, "processFoo(${body}, ${bean:#{{foo}}})")` | `No bean could be found in the registry for: #foo-1` |
| `.bean(fooConsumer, "processFoo(${body}, ${bean:{{foo}}})")` | `No bean could be found in the registry for: foo-1` |

Surely it's possible to do this since the examples show passing a `myClient` bean to a `aws2-s3` endpoint using the `#{{myClient}}` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one way of using these route templates like I'm trying to here, but it doesn't feel very clean. Perhaps I'm trying to use these in a way they aren't intended to be used. Anyhow, to get it to work, I created a inner `ServiceActivator` class in the class defining the route template:

```java
private class ServiceActivator {
  private final Foo foo;

  public ServiceActivator(final RouteTemplateContext routeTemplateContext) {
    this.foo = (
      routeTemplateContext
        .getLocalBeanRepository ()
        .lookupByNameAndType    ("foo", Foo.class)
      );
  }

  @Handler
  public void processFoo(@Body final String body) {
    // do something 
  }
}
```

Then, I updated the route template to:

1. Remove the declaration of `foo` because having the definition makes Camel  attempt to create a default value for it.
2. Create this `ServiceActivator` on route creation.
3. Reference the `ServiceActivator` in the `bean` definition of the route.

```java
routeTemplate("myTemplate")
  // Define the parameters for the route template
  .templateParameter ("fromEndpointUri")
  .templateBean      ("serviceActivator, ServiceActivator.class, ServiceActivator::new)

  // Define the route.
  .from("{{fromEndpointUri}}")
  .bean("{{serviceActivator}}")
```

And left my templated route as:

```java
templatedRoute("myTemplate")
  .routeId   ("myTemplateRoute")
  .parameter ("fromEndpointUri", "direct:test")
  .bean      ("foo", Foo.class, ignored -> new Foo());
```

Again, it seems almost like a hack rather than using this feature of a Camel in a way that it was intended to be used. From what I could tell stepping through the code, the route template parameters and beans are only available at the time of route creation, so this was a way of capturing all of that information during route creation to be used in later executions of the route.